# Django retrieves wrong datetime objects (timezone overridden) from postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timezone

I am encountering an issue with Django, psycopg, and PostgreSQL regarding the handling of timezone-aware datetimes. Below are the details of my setup and the problem I'm facing:

#### Environment

| Library | Version |
| --- | --- |
| psycopg | 3.1.18 |
| Django | 4.2.10 |
| PostgreSQL | 16.1 |

#### Issue Description

I have a Django model with a `DateTimeField`, which creates a `timestamp with timezone` column in PostgreSQL. When I create a new model instance with a timezone-aware datetime and save it to the database, the datetime is stored correctly as verified by viewing it in database viewers like pgAdmin or DataGrip.

However, when retrieving the data back in Django, the datetime appears with the wrong offset. Specifically, it seems to override the original timezone offset to 0 (UTC), while the time remains unchanged, leading to incorrect datetime values.

#### Example

- Datetime passed to the model: `2024-02-18 01:46:29+01:00`
- Datetime stored in the database (viewed with DataGrip): `2024-02-18 01:46:29.000000 +01:00`
- Datetime retrieved in Django: `2024-02-18 01:46:29+00:00`

This discrepancy suggests that instead of simply converting the time to UTC, Django changes the timezone to UTC but keeps the time from the UTC+1 timezone, which is incorrect.

#### Django Settings

I have the following settings in my `settings.py`:

```py
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

I experimented with the `TIME_ZONE` setting in the `DATABASES` variable, setting it to `TIME_ZONE`: `Europe/Zurich`, which corrected the timezone to `UTC+1`. However, this solution seems to adjust the timezone in which I receive the data, not the underlying issue of incorrect timezone handling.

Additional Notes
When using psycopg directly (without Django), this problem does not occur, and the data is returned with the correct timezone. This suggests that the issue might be within Django's handling of timezones.

Questions
Am I misunderstanding Django's timezone handling?
Is there a configuration step I am missing, or is this behavior potentially a bug?
I would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I identified the root cause of the issue we've been encountering. The problem originated from PostgreSQL. However, due to the way Django handles datetime responses, the bug was only observable on the Django side.

### Problem in PostgreSQL:

The issue was that PostgreSQL was not setting the timezone as expected. Although the actual time was correct, setting the timezone to anything worked fine, except for UTC. When UTC was specified, PostgreSQL returned the time in the system's timezone instead of UTC. This behavior was confirmed through testing with `psql`:

```
slick26=# SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/London';
SET
slick26=# SHOW TIMEZONE;
   TimeZone
---------------
Europe/London
(1 row)

slick26=# SELECT now();
            now
-------------------------------
2024-03-03 12:27:16.057474+00
(1 row)

slick26=#
slick26=# SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SET
slick26=# SHOW TIMEZONE;
TimeZone
----------
UTC
(1 row)

slick26=# SELECT now();
            now
-------------------------------
2024-03-03 13:28:54.533239+01
(1 row)

slick26=#
```

The underlying issue was related to running PostgreSQL within a container. To align the container's timezone correctly, I mounted the following volumes and set the corresponding environment variables:

- Volumes:

  - `/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro`
  - `/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro`
- Environment Variables:

  - `TZ: Europe/Zurich`
  - `PGTZ: Europe/Zurich`

However, the attempt to mount `localtime` did not yield the expected outcome; the symlink continued to point to UTC.

### Problem in Django:

Django establishes the connection timezone as UTC. However, when the database responds with a datetime value in UTC+1, the discrepancy arises. While other clients would display the returned result as is, Django overrides it with the expected timezone (UTC in this case), leading to incorrect datetime values being displayed.